# Android TTS error

Tags: android

How do i implement text to speech in my app to support minSdk 15? current API is 24. I get an error in this method.

```
  public void TextToSpeech(string Text)
    {
    myTTS.speak(Text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    }
```

error says that speak is deprecated and I tried replacing that with this

```
 public void TextToSpeech(string Text)
    {
    myTTS.speak(Text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,"myTTSid");
    }
```

a recent version but that is also not supported on the minSdk 15 i want to use. Is there a way I can implement TTS to supported the minSdk 15 i'm targetting?

Comment: You can ignore the deprecation and create a method that chooses the newer API and older API depending on the current run-time

Comment: great! please can you show me how to implement that?

Comment: `I get an error` **NO**: You get a **warning**. You can blatantly ignore it.

Comment: @mystic Sure, take a look at my answer. If that suit your needs, mark my answer as accepted. :)

Comment: @Rotwang Technically you are correct, no shame in using the deprecated API but it is a good habit to always code for it.

Comment: @AlexanderMayatsky Yes, you should. But probably, for a beginner, it's easier to skip it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void speak(String text) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        myTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "myTTSid");
    } else {
        myTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated